# Directory transfer from Linux -> Windows; 255 Character limit error

Tags: linux, windows, filenames

I need to copy a very large directory from a linux server to a windows machine; the directory is very large and contains directories that go as deep as having 50+ subdirectories. So as you could probably imagine, Windows errors out when trying to copy the files over.

Is their any sort of script or existing program which could rename or move all the folders and subfolders withinin the main directory to something within 255 character limit as well as output a text file mapping the new names to the old?

Comment: Have you tried `rsync(1)` yet? Neat tool.

Comment: What 255 character limit are you referring to? How did you try to copy them? Drag and drop? scp?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest your better option is to zip the files in Linux and keep them zipped in Windows. Zip files can store long names and deep paths. Windows can browse a zip without any additional software.